# VB - Change application text with button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want my `button1` to change the text of my `form1` from "My Application name" to "My Application name2" by the click of a button.

What I've tried:

```
form1.text = (textbox1.text)
```

But no luck.

Any Help?

Comment: IIRC, that should be `form1.Text = textbox1.Text` (caps).  In what subroutine are you placing this code?

Comment: What version of vb.net are you using? Have you checked to make sure that `textbox1.text` is actually valid text?  Is `form1` in scope of where you're running the control?

Comment: `form1.text` does not change your application's name, it only changes form caption of the default instance of the form. In most cases you would use `Me.Text = "new caption"`, but it also would *not* change your application's name. Why do you want to change it at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot can change the form name at run time. The name of a Form can be anything you want, but it must stay the same throughout. I can't imagine however why would you ever want to change the name in runtime as its not visible to the users. The form's caption on the other hand is a completly different thing, adressed in @matzone's answer.

Comment: I had assumed the OP really wanted to know how to change the form's caption, which is most definitely possible. So this answer isn't really correct.

Comment: @siride why did you assume that when he said _"I want my button1 to change the name of my form1"_?

Comment: You can't change the *name*, but you can certainly change the *caption* (i.e., what the user sees displayed on the title bar). Just set the `Me.Text` property to whatever string you like. The user never sees the `Name` property anyway, so there's no point in changing it. It's just for the programmer's use.

Comment: @MrD: well, for one, the example code he gave changed the Text property, which is for the caption. And secondly, I can't think of a reason why you'd ever care to change the name, unless you were doing accessibility stuff (and then only maybe), and I doubt a user doing that would need help on such a basic topic.

Comment: True senseless, but thats what he asked. You are just downvoting out of jelousy so either take your downvotes back or post an answer that responds to what he meant and I'll gladly delete my question and let you have the points.

Comment: @MrD: I'm not downvoting out of jealousy (no idea where you got that idea from), I'm downvoting because you're wrong and your answer isn't a good one. There's already a good answer by matzone and it is, not surprisingly, upvoted.

Comment: his answer is great but it responds to another question; mine doesn't, how is it wrong or bad?

Comment: @matzone, sorry should have checked. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant about Main Form caption/text .. It has to be work with

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Me.Text = Textbox1.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: May I know what name do you see in your application ?

Comment: @user2395588: that answer is wrong. You can change the form's caption.

Comment: @siride : I'm using VB 2005 and it did works .. what VB you're using ?

Comment: @matzone: your answer is fine. I'm talking about the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try just with following code:

```
Me.Text = Textbox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say change **"Name"** you are talking about changing the word that represents the form throughout the coding. This means it can ONLY HAVE ONE NAME because it woudl be a chaos if it had more than one.

When you say change **"Text"** you are talking about the "Title" of the form. The text that shows up there in the left upper corner.

To change the **Name** you just need to click the form on the designer and then go to properties and scroll down until you find the Name option.
You can change **Text** the same way or programatically writing:

```
Me.Text = "MyApplicationName 2"
```

Hope it helps.